# how to convert hash+string to number in free marker

Tags: freemarker

I'm struggling to convert hash+string to number in free marker. How I can resolve this issue:

```
<#assign varnetweight = varitem.varquantity * example.examplevar />
```

```
or "*" right-hand operand: Expected a number, but this has evaluated to a hash+string (wrapper: com.netledger.templates.model.StringModel):
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: you need two numbers for your multiplication.

I tested your configuration with https://try.freemarker.apache.org/:

This configuration is working as you access a number with `example.examplevar`.
[image: This is working as you access a number]

Here you don't access a number but another data structure that cannot be resolved to a number:

[image]

So please provide your complete data for us to see why it is wrong. Or maybe this already helps you.